# Neo4j - Embedded Database

Tags: rest, neo4j

I am building a web application that is going to use Neo4J. I will have a REST API build in Java, that  will consume the Neo4j Embedded version. Is there any problem with this architecture?

Is it better to use other approach? Neo4j server?

Thanks!

Comment: You should know why you want to use embedded, in general Neo4j Server + extensions for high performance use-cases is more common.

Comment: @Michel Hunger: I will need to make batch operation in neo4j. That's why I prefer use embedded version.

Answer (score 0):

I found embedded approach

### good because of:

1. Use of Java API
2. Performance
3. Transaction handling

### bad because of:

1. Lack of manager web interface: There is a way to run embedded Jetty, but it doesn't work for me when used in webapp and relies on use of many deprecated classes
2. Lack of CLI interface
3. Above points make it very hard for development. If you need to fix or alter database using cypher, you need to stop your webapp and start Neo server on same db folder.
4. backup of running server (community version) and runtime fixes in production might be impossible.